# VS Code and Remote SSH with WSL2 debian ssh-agent

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-remote, vscode-remote-ssh

I have wsl2 Debian setup with yubikey and running ssh-agent:

```
export | grep SSH_AUTH_SOCK
declare -x SSH_AUTH_SOCK="/run/user/1000//yubikey-agent/yubikey-agent.sock"
```

I do not have any agents running on a Windows machine, just using `usbipd attach --wsl` to bridge yubikey USB device to remote wsl2 instance and running systemd service yubikey-agent there (native linux way). *And the problem is if device is attached to remote wsl2 - it cannot be used on local windows anymore.*

In VS code I try to make an SSH Remote connection to a different remote linux machine, VS code of course using either local Windows OpenSSH.exe or with some tricks (https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-remote-release/issues/937#issuecomment-1654832590) wsl ssh binary. Both are unaware of running ssh-agent on the wsl2 instance and they try to find some id_rsa file in some typical directories - so I cannot connect.

Is there any way to create a remote SSH connection in VS Code via wsl2 ssh client with proper ssh-agent?